# ¿Cómo convertir el END AS decHorasEfectivas a formato horas?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

¿Cómo puedo convertir el `END AS decHorasEfectivas` a formato horas?

Por ejemplo cualquier tipo de hora *10:30*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Ok muy bien, Pero a lo que pregunte si hay forma de convertirlo oh es imposible.?

Comment: Si querés que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, te recomiendo seguir el consejo de Gbianchi. Ten en cuenta que nosotros no tenemos tiempo y/o ganas de ponernos a transcribir código a partir de una imagen para poder probarlo. Al poner tu código como imagen, reduces enormemente tus posibilidades de ser ayudado. Todo tiene su motivo, sea mantener la calidad del sitio o que sea más facil ayudarte.